# sqlite .net 1.0.92.0 entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

It's not duplicate question, because it's for new release of sqlite.
I can't build entity data model database first from sqlite database, here is my packages :

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.92.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.92.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.92.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.92.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

when I want to build entity data model with "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" it can't and give me this error :

Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuid your project before performing this action.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the EF6 assemblies were not in the references. By manually adding the system assemblies System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Entity.Design solved the problem, though VS gave me a warning about not using the latest EF, but the designer finally worked OK.

Comment: you are saying if I add those two assemblies you mentioned , it will be work?! cause I test it and it's not! :(

Comment: It did solve the problem for me, and I'm sorry it didn't work for you. :(

Comment: I did a little experiment, and managed to reproduce the working behaviour.
What I did:
#1 create a new console project
#2 NuGet install **System.Data.Sqlite.Core** package, which does not install EF6
#3 Add a Data model
#4 be only able to select EF5 adapter at model generation
#5 see my tables, and have a model geerated from them!

let me know if it works for you!